# Does browser interpret html tags which are inside input tag or not

Tags: html

**I have updated it. let me make it more clear**

```
<input type="text" value='<div>hello</div><strong>'/>good day
```

**what I have got**

input box having default value as `<div>hello</div><strong>` inside it and the text following the input `good day` does not inherit the `strong tag` it looks normal font size and it is not interpreted by browser and this is what i want.

http://jsfiddle.net/UrGpC/3/ This is what i really want to be but does it work in all browsers ?

The browser does not treat the html tags which are inside the `input value` as the normal flow of html tags from my experiment or does it interpret them ?

Comment: why don't you give it a try in a few browsers, and see what happens?

Comment: you have put this value=" but hasn't close it, put value="" and tell us.

Comment: @Dan I have tried it let me update ! I just want to know its a good way of doing things and any other documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and see, it doesn't interpret it as an element, it get rendered as plain text, try loading jQuery and change it thru it:

```
$('#test').html("ok");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nd87/UrGpC/

Next time you should Test it and explain what you have tried

Comment: I think your answer is what iam looking for .. kindly see my updated question

Answer (score 1):

Well you can try this:

```
<input type="text" value="<div>hello</div><strong>" />
```

**PD:** You forgot to close the value atributte :P

---

**EDIT:**

It's works for me, is so strange... Anyway if it doesn't work you can try **& lt;** and **& gt;** method.

```
&lt;div&gt;hello&lt;/div&gt;
```

As **Wesley Murch** said. ;)

Comment: Did you try it..? It doesn't work. value is actually converted to text

Comment: @lkillnukes ok from your code how do you see it treats it as an HTML element? It simply renders the text not an actual div.

Comment: You want to strong another word on the input?

Comment: @Ikillnukes i dont want to render any element i want input value to be just a plain text and it should not rendered by browser . thats what i want

Comment: What browser do you use? (It works for me as you can see here)
http://gyazo.com/35a4c6e229369b1f0c78b22c66e44626

Comment: @Ikillnukes I dont want to strong any another word . I want you to confirm me the tags inside input value are a plain text or whether they are interpreted by browsers .

Comment: So? You can try **& lt;** and **& gt;** method as I sais before. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this recently, but gave up.  According to this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-value-INPUT, input value is CDATA, which seems to mean basically only ordinary characters can be included.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA